# Open url in app with multiple button click one by one

Tags: react-native

I tried to open the URL with on Press event. The link with first button works but while clicking other button they don't work.

This problem arise: {console.error : "An error occurred", {frameToPop" :1, "code" : "EUNSPECIFIED"}

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,
    Text, 
    Button,
    Linking
     } from 'react-native';

export default class Website extends React.Component{   

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        isLoading:true
    }
}   
render(){

    return (
        <View style = {styles.container}>
            <MyHeader screen="School Website" onMenuPress= {() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} onHomePress= {() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}/>

            <Button title="School Website Link" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL("http://kaskimodernized.edu.np/").catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));}} />                

            <Button title="School Facebook Link" onPress={ ()=>{  Linking.openURL(" https://www.facebook.com/kaskimodernized/  ").catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));}} /> 

            <Button title="School Instagram Link" onPress={ ()=>{ Linking.openURL(" https://www.instagram.com/kaskimodernizedacademy/?hl=en ").catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));}} /> 

            <Footer/>
        </View>

    );
}
}
)
```

expected to open all the links when i click the button

Comment: Anyone here who could give valueable  suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in your url string at the start and in the end of it.